# Querying Oracle geometry data type

Tags: sql, geometry, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, sdo-geometry

How to query or find the geometry data type a given Oracle Database is using in SQL Developer (i.e. SDO_Geometry, ST_Geometry, etc)?

I thought I could just describe a feature class within the database and get the result, but it just returns the field types. The geometry field just returns 'NUMBER', which isn't helpful.

Comment: The type returned by `DESCRIBE` for a native geometry column should be `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY` or `MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY`.  If you're getting `NUMBER` it probably isn't a native geometry column.  Please **edit** the question to include the version of Oracle and a DESCRIBE output. You should also include `SELECT * FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` output.

Comment: Note that ArcGIS enterprise feature classes can be stored in MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY, SDE.ST_GEOMETRY, SDELOB, or SDEBINARY storage types.  The latter two use a Fn table to store the actual geometry with a NUMBER(38) foreign key in the "geometry_column" of the business table.  So if ArcGIS sees the geometry column, but SQL Developer doesn't, you haven't used the appropriate DBTUNE keyword to request table creation with geometry storage the native format.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the SDO metadata table to get spatial information:

```
select * from MDSYS.ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA where TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
```

Comment: Strange. I tried this query and it returned an empty result (not an error, just no data attached to the result)

Comment: It sounds like you don't have any Oracle spatial columns properly set up.

Comment: This table has to be populated manually. It won't give the user any information if the data wasn't inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure SQL, we can find the data type of a column using the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` view:

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE UPPER(OWNER) = 'THE_SCHEMA' AND UPPER(TABLE_NAME) = 'THE_TABLE'
```

One of the result columns is `DATA_TYPE`. Note that there is a `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` if you are connecting as the schema that holds the table of interest.

We could also use `DESCRIBE`:

```
DESCRIBE THE_SCHEMA.THE_TABLE
```

But the result of that command cannot be queried any further.

We can also use `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` to try to discover what spatial columns we have:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'SDO_GEOMETRY';
```

`ST_GEOMETRY` can be easily added to the `WHERE` clause. Based on [Vince's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163369/querying-oracle-geometry-data-type#comment242318_163369), the following filter seems like a good place to start:

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE
    DATA_TYPE LIKE '%GEOM%' OR
    DATA_TYPE LIKE '%SDE%'
;
```

Note that neither Oracle nor ArcGIS will be able to do much with the columns unless the `USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` has an entry for each geometry column and a spatial index is added.